# save xml allocated in server wp7

Tags: xml, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

i need to save a xml file from a server.. i found a code to make the download but i don't  understand how to save the file into memory.. How can i do that? I search in google and i have this:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
        Uri xmlUri = new Uri("http://dl.dropbox.com/13258/file.xml", UriKind.Absolute);
        downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(Downloaded);
        downloader.DownloadStringAsync(xmlUri);




    }

    void Downloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result == null || e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error downloading the xml-file");
        }
        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Download succeed");
        }
    }
```

I want to make the download and save it into the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have will download a file from a server.  In Downloaded() you will need to add some code to save the file you have just downloaded.

On WP7 You save files to isolated storage.  This is a application specific file system you can use to save any files you want your application to use.  The following link describes how isolated storage can be used:

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-read-and-save-text-files

In your case add this to the Else in Downloaded()

```
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
using (StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("File.Xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, myIsolatedStorage)))
{
    writeFile.WriteLine(e.Result);
    writeFile.Close();
}
```

Take care with the FileMode Enumeration Type, the example above uses OpenOrCreate which  will open an existing or Create a new file, i.e. overwrite any existing file with that name in the root folder of isolated storage.  Details on this enumeration are here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx